# AspectJ - Android IllegalStateException after adding firebase dependency

Tags: android, firebase, aop, aspectj

Using Ibotta, an AOP gradle plugin for android, seems not working after adding below dependency

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'`

Actual Result:

Build was successful and seems not creating all dex

Runtime Error:

```
Application class not found in dex path list.
```

AOP Log showing below error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting .,<, or ;, but found - while unpacking <MessageType:Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaaa<TMessageType;TBuilderType;>;BuilderType:Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzzw<TMessageType;TBuilderType;>;>Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzyj<TMessageType;TBuilderType;>;
    at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(GenericSignatureParser.java:204)
    at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(GenericSignatureParser.java:155)
    at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseFormalTypeParameter(GenericSignatureParser.java:130)
    at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseAsClassSignature(GenericSignatureParser.java:51)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.UnresolvedType.forGenericTypeSignature(UnresolvedType.java:275)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:479)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:453)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addAspectsFromJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:265)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addLibraryJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:238)
```

Below added the required code to reproduce this.

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

project build.gradle

```
 repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.ibotta:plugin:1.1.0"
    }
```

app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.ibotta.gradle.aop"

dependencies {
        //AspectJ
        implementation "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.6"
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
    }
```

AspectLogging class

```
@Aspect
class AOPLog {

    @Pointcut("within(com.example.aopdemo..*) && execution(* *(..))")
    fun allMethods() {
    }

    @Around("allMethods()")
    @Throws(Throwable::class)
    open fun onMethodAdvice(joinPoint: JoinPoint?): Any? {
        val methodSignature = joinPoint!!.signature as MethodSignature
        val methodName = methodSignature.name
        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        val result = (joinPoint as ProceedingJoinPoint).proceed()
        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
        Log.e("LoggingVM", "$methodName ---> $endTime")
        return result
    }
}
```

Note: Firebase dependency is just added and not using anywhere in the demo app.

com.example.aopdemo package just have a launcher activity, and invoking some methods on onCreate method. It was tracking all the methods before firebase added. After adding, getting above errors.

Comment: Where is your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? There is no code, no build configuration, not even an AspectJ version mentioned here.

Comment: What do you mean by "Build was successful and seems not creating all dex"? What is it not creating that you are expecting to be created?

Answer (score 2):

> Using Ibotta, an AOP library for android

It is not an AOP library but a Gradle plugin for people wishing to weave AspectJ aspects into their Android target apps or libraries, see [here](https://github.com/Ibotta/gradle-aspectj-pipeline-plugin).

What strikes me as odd in your error message is the package name `com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaaa` - please note the hyphens. Actually, hyphen (`"-"`) characters in package names are illegal, see [Java naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

If Firebase itself or maybe some kind of code converter or obfuscator uses `firebase-auth-api` instead of something like `firebase_auth_api` or `firebase.auth.api` (depending on what it looks like in the original code base), it is no surprise at all that it derails the AspectJ signature parser. I wonder which compiler even permits that nowadays.

Fix the package name, then I guess the AspectJ problem will disappear too. The error reported by AspectJ is valid, the problem is outside of AspectJ.

---

**Update:** I looked at the AAR file you added to your class path and indeed it contains an illegal package name with obfuscated classes, probably on purpose in order to make it more difficult to work with and manipulate those classes:

```
$ unzip firebase-auth-20.0.3.aar -d firebase-auth
Archive:  firebase-auth-20.0.3.aar
  inflating: firebase-auth/AndroidManifest.xml
  inflating: firebase-auth/R.txt
  inflating: firebase-auth/classes.jar
  inflating: firebase-auth/proguard.txt
  inflating: firebase-auth/third_party_licenses.json
  inflating: firebase-auth/third_party_licenses.txt

$ unzip -l firebase-auth/classes.jar | grep firebase-auth-api | head -n 10
     1209  2021-02-26 09:54   com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zza.class
     1032  2021-02-26 09:54   com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaa.class
    10997  2021-02-26 09:54   com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaaa.class
     4291  2021-02-26 09:54   com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaab.class
      172  2021-02-26 09:54   com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaac.class
      275  2021-02-26 09:54   com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaad.class
      192  2021-02-26 09:54   com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaae.class
      525  2021-02-26 09:54   com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaaf.class
     2430  2021-02-26 09:54   com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaag.class
      373  2021-02-26 09:54   com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaah.class
```

Unfortunately, this also stops legal use cases from working. You may want to [raise an issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues) or alternatively make sure to exclude Firebase or at least its internal packages when using AspectJ, e.g. via `!within(com.google.android.gms.internal..*)`. Or do your aspects actually want to modify anything in Firebase?

---

**Update 2:** Inside Ibotta, there is a [source code comment](https://github.com/Ibotta/gradle-aspectj-pipeline-plugin/blob/develop/plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/ibotta/gradle/aop/PipelineAopWeaverPlugin.kt#L21) as follows:

> A Gradle plugin that performs AOP weaving using a technique recommended by Gradle reps. It ***taps into Android's bytecode manipulation pipeline*** which is a far more logical approach.
>
> The basic idea is:
>
> 1. Change the Kotlin and Java compile output directories.
> 2. Copy the Kotlin/Java compiled output to one directory.
> 3. Weave the combined Kotlin/Java classes.
> 4. Be registered as a bytecode generator so that Android recognizes the custom AOP weaving as a formal step in the build pipeline.

Maybe in using this approach instead of calling the stand-alone AspectJ compiler, somehow the byte code weaver has to load and see all classes, even the ones the normal AspectJ compiler would ignore due to the `within(com.example.aopdemo..*)` in your sample aspect or the safe-guarding `!within(com.google.android.gms.internal..*)` I suggested. Either way, that it works after you changed the Gradle build plugin tells me that you should raise an issue for the Ibotta project (not for Firebase like I initially thought). Actually, it seems that you already did that, see [issue #5](https://github.com/Ibotta/gradle-aspectj-pipeline-plugin/issues/5).

---

**Update 3:** A while ago, the [Ibotta maintainer said](https://github.com/Ibotta/gradle-aspectj-pipeline-plugin/issues/5#issuecomment-794723847) that you should use the tool's own filtering feature and use something like

```java
aopWeave {
    filter = "com/example/aopdemo"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I have updated issue with minimum code to reproduce this. Also doesn't seems like it's a package naming convention issue, as getting similar error for different google-play-service dependencies ````java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting .,<, or ;, but found authapi while unpacking <R::Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Result;>Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/internal/BaseImplementation$ApiMethodImpl<TR;Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/auth-api/zzr;>;
 at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(GenericSignatureParser.java:204)````

Comment: Of course it is the same in `com/google/android/gms/internal/auth-api/zzr` → `auth-api` is an illegal package name and `com.google.android.gms.internal` even is the same base package.

Comment: yeah, you are right.. i tried excluding those packages by adding !within, but was not working

Comment: Just now tried using a different plugin "io.freefair.gradle:android-gradle-plugins" and it is working

Comment: Oh, so the error message was appearing during **build time**? I maybe misunderstood and thought the message appeared during **app runtime**. I actually did not try to use your build tool so far, but tried recreating the runtime problem with a manually manipulated class using a hyphen/dash in its package name, and it worked when instantiating that class using reflection. The thing is, in byte code hyphens in package names are allowed, just not in source code for compilation, which is why obfuscators like to use that as a trick.

Comment: See **update 2** in which I explained the probable reason why it works with Freefair plugin, but not with Ibotta plugin.

Comment: In **update 3** I quoted a workaround for Ibotta. I know that you moved on to another tool (Freefair) according to your previous comment, but this question is still listed as unanswered concerning Ibotta and I believe, I did answer it adequately, both with an explanation why it does not work and a workaround. I also engaged in discussion with the maintainer about the tool's limitation. Maybe you would be so kind as to accept and upvote my answer in order to close the question. Thank you so much.